# part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql

```
"Project nr"    "Task"                "Task deadline"  "Task Type Production"

456             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
456             Leave production      3 april 2013      Leave Production
456             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
123             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
123             Leave production      6 april 2013      Leave Production
123             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
789             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
789             Leave production      9 april 2013      Leave Production
789             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
```

I need a list like above I want to sort on the date of 'Leave production' The project nr has to stay ingroups of 3 like the list above.

I already have this SQL. The list is working but the sort is not working. The error is: The multi-part identifier "task.[task deadline]" could not be bound. I already had a suggestion but still errors. How do I get is sorted?

This is the list i get:

```
Project Nr     Task             TaskDate
0053           Packed           2013-02-05 17:00:00.000
0053           Leave Production 2011-04-26 17:00:00.000
0053           Flight Date      2011-04-22 17:00:00.000
0071           Leave Production 2011-06-24 17:00:00.000
0081           Leave Production 2012-03-09 17:00:00.000
0081-01        Leave Production 2012-03-09 17:00:00.000
```

This is the SQl:

```
    SELECT  [Project nr], Task, TaskDate
        FROM    (
        SELECT   MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
                ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Packed' 
                            THEN [Task deadline] 
                        END) AS Packed
                ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production' 
                            THEN [Task deadline]
                        END) AS [Leave Production]
                ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date' 
                           THEN [Task deadline]
                        END) AS [Flight Date]
       FROM    MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
               LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
                    ON MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID 
                LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
                    ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID 
               LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
               ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
    WHERE (MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskIsProjectSummary = 0) 
    GROUP BY MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
    )     data
        UNPIVOT
    (
      TaskDate
      for [Task] in ([Pack],[Leave Production],[Flight Date])
    ) piv
  SELECT  [Project nr], Task, TaskDate
  FROM    (
  SELECT   MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
        ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Packed' 
                    THEN [Task deadline] 
                END) AS Packed
        ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production' 
                    THEN [Task deadline]
                END) AS [Leave Production]
        ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date' 
                    THEN [Task deadline]
                END) AS [Flight Date]
   FROM    MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
        LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
            ON MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID 
        LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
            ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID 
        LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
            ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
   WHERE (MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskIsProjectSummary = 0) 
  GROUP BY MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
  ) data
  UNPIVOT
  (
     TaskDate
    for [Task] in ([Pack],[Leave Production],[Flight Date])
   ) piv

This line should do the sort, but i get an error
    ORDER BY    data.[Task deadline]

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
The multi-part identifier "data.[Leave Production]" could not be bound.
The problem lies in the fact that I need a pivot list that is sorted on the second line of the  group
      0053           Packed           2013-02-05 17:00:00.000
 -->> 0053           Leave Production 2011-04-26 17:00:00.000
      0053           Flight Date      2011-04-22 17:00:00.000
```

I have send this question befor, but the answers don't work unfortunately. Perhaps I need another setup. Any ideas?

Comment: A little editing, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your data subquery appears to have two fields - project nr and flight date.  If you want to order by anything in data, those are your only two choices.

Answer (score 0):

So I may be misunderstanding your requirement, but this is what I came up with:

```
with M([Project Nr], [Task], [taskdate]) as (
    select '0053', 'Packed', '2013-02-05 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0053 ', 'Leave Production', '2011-04-26 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0053', 'Flight Date', '2011-04-22 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0071', 'Leave Production', '2011-06-24 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0071', 'Packed', '2011-03-09 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0071', 'Flight Date', '2011-07-09 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0081', 'Leave Production', '2013-06-24 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0081', 'Packed', '2011-03-09 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0081', 'Flight Date', '2011-07-09 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0091', 'Leave Production', '2006-06-24 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0091', 'Packed', '2011-03-09 17:00:00.000' union
    select '0091', 'Flight Date', '2011-07-09 17:00:00.000' 
)

select 
    * 
from 
    M AllData
    inner join (
        select 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by TaskDate) as ProductionOrder, 
            [Project Nr] 
        from 
            M
        where
            task = 'Leave Production'
    )
ProductionOrder
    on ProductionOrder.[Project Nr] = AllData.[Project Nr]
Order by
    ProductionOrder
```

It basically gets all of your Leave Production tasks, assigns them a windowed row number in order, joins that back to your project list on the project number, then sorts your full data set by that windowed number.

One of your problems is that you're doing the multi-column pivot to get the max deadline dates and then trying to ... unpivot it? So you're defeating the purpose of all that MAX(CASE .. ) logic at the end. The other issue is that for example your data query has a result set of

Project Nr, Packed, Leave Production, Flight Date

but you're trying to unpivot using Task Date and Task and those don't exist in your source query.